# Multiple Reference and Dereference in C

Tags: c, pointers, reference, dereference

Can somebody clealry explain me the concept behind multiple reference and dereference ? why does the following program gives output as 'h' ?

```
int main()
{
char *ptr = "hello";
printf("%c\n", *&*&*ptr);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

and not this , instead it produces 'd' ?

```
int main()
{
char *ptr = "hello";
printf("%c\n", *&*&ptr);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

I read that consecutive use of '*' and '&' cancels each other but this explanation does not provide the reason behind two different outputs generated in above codes?

Comment: "use of '*' and '&' cancels each other" so try `printf("%c\n", ptr);`. Think.

Comment: In the second case, you start by applying the `&` operator to the pointer itself, so you get a `char **`. Then you keep referencing and dereferencing, so you end up printing the pointer value instead of what it points to.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

The first program produces `h` because `&`s and `*`s "cancel" each other: "dereferencing an address of X" gives back the X:

- `ptr` - a pointer to the initial character of `"hello"` literal
- `*ptr` - dereference of a pointer to the initial character, i.e. the initial character
- `&*ptr` the address of the dereference of a pointer to the initial character, i.e. a pointer to the initial character, i.e. `ptr` itself

And so on. As you can see, a pair `*&` brings you back to where you have started, so you can eliminate all such pairs from your dereference / take address expressions. Therefore, your first program's `printf` is equivalent to

```
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
```

The second program has undefined behavior, because a pointer is being passed to `printf` with the format specifier of `%c`. If you pass the same expression to `%s`, the word `hello` would be printed:

```
printf("%s\n", *&*&ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets go through the important parts of the program:

```
char *ptr = "hello";
```

makes a pointer to `char` which points to the string literal `"hello"`. Now, for the confusing part:

```
printf("%c\n", *&*&*ptr);
```

Here, `%c` expects a `char`. Let us look into what type `*&*&*ptr` is. `ptr` is a `char*`. Applying the dereference operator(`*`) gives a `char`. Applying the address-of operator to this `char` gives back the `char*`. This is repeated again, and finally, the `*` at the end gives us a `char`, the first character of the string literal `"hello"`, which gets printed.

---

In the second program, in `*&*&ptr`, you first apply the `&` operator, which gives a `char**`. Applying `*` on this gives back the `char*`. This is repeated again and finally , we get a `char*`. But `%c` expects a `char`, not a `char*`. So, the second program exhibits [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per the C11 standard (emphasis mine):

> **7.21.6.1 The fprintf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 9. If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.<sup>282</sup> **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

So, basically, anything can happen when you execute the second program. Your program might crash, emit a segmentation-fault, output weird things, or do something else.

---

BTW, you are right about saying:

> I read that consecutive use of '*' and '&' cancels each other

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down what `*&*&*ptr` actually is, but first, remember that when applying `*` to a pointer, it gives you what that pointer points to. On the other hand, when applying `&` to a variable, it gives you the address in memory for that variable.

Now, after getting a steady ground, let's see what you have here:
`ptr` is a pointer to a `char`, thus when doing `*ptr` it gives you the data which `ptr` points to,  in this case, `ptr` points to a string `"hello"`, however, a `char` can hold only one char, not a whole string, right? so, it point to the beginning of such a string, which is the first character in it, aka `h`.

Moving on...`*&*&*ptr=*&*&(*ptr) = *&*&('h')= *&*(&'h') = *&*(ptr)=*&(*ptr) = *&('h')= *ptr = 'h'`

If you apply the same pattern on the next function, I'm pretty sure you can figure it out.

**SUMMARY:** read pointers from the right to the left!