# What is the correct format for the address (&) and indirection operator

Tags: c++, pointers, addressof

I've seen many different ways of writing the address-of operator (&) and the  indirection operator (*)

If I'm not mistaken it should be like this:

```
//examples
int var = 5;
int *pVar = var;

cout << var << endl; //this prints the value of var which is 5

cout << &var << endl; //this should print the memory address of var

cout << *&var << endl; //this should print the value at the memory address of var

cout << *pVar << endl; //this should print the value in whatever the pointer is pointing to

cout << &*var << endl; //I've heard that this would cancel the two out
```

What would happen if for example you wrote `&var` as `& var` with a space between the two? Common syntax I have seen: `char* line = var;`, `char * line = var;`, and `char *line = var;`.

Comment: Have you tried this out?

Comment: Related (in C: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30423656/335858)

Comment: In this area, whitespace is significant *only* to the extent that it's used to separate tokens. For example, if you have `char const *foo`, you need to leave the space between `char` and `const` (to keep it from being treated as a single token `charconst`), but the rest is irrelevant--you can remove or insert as much white space on each side of the `*` as you want, and it makes no difference to the meaning (likewise with `&`). There are widely diverging opinions as to what use of white space maximizes readability.

Comment: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rl-ptr

Comment: A modern compiler should stop right here: `int *pVar = var;`. An integer is not a pointer. (This was legal in C, but my C++ doesn't go back far enough to know for certain if it was ever legal in C++) All compilers should reject `&*var` because before applying `&` it will apply `*` and you can only `*`, dereference, a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, `int *pVar = var;` is incorrect; this does not store the address of `var`, but it stores the address "5", which will lead to a compilation error saying:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:9:15: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
>     int *pVar = var;
>                 ^~~
> ```

`var` needs to be references in the initialization of `*pvar`:

```
int *pVar = &var;
```

**Secondly**, `cout << &*var << endl;` will also cause an error at compilation because `var` is not a pointer (`int*`) type variable:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>   main.cpp:19:13: error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
>      cout << &*var << endl; //I've heard that this would cancel the two out
>                ^~~
> ```

---

Now, to answer your question, adding whitespace between the referencing (`&`) operator and the pointer (`*`) operator will make absolutely no difference to the compiler. The only time it makes a difference is when you want to separate 2 tokens; like `const` and `string` for example. Running the following code just to exaggerate an example of what you are asking:

```
cout <<             &             var << endl;  
cout <<                            *                    & var << endl;
cout <<                                   *pVar << endl;
```

Yields the same results as those from code without so many spaces:

```
0x7ffe243c3404
5
5
```